# Is there any (built in) way to make a request from sever side on behalf of the current session?

Tags: asp.net-core, session, request

In a request i would like to make an independent asynchronous other request... not to an other web site or web api, but within the same web application.

Should be routine task, but I want this request be within the very same session as the current request. Only to overengineered solutions come into my mind: (well, I know, even the thing I want to do sounds overengineered)

- use `HttpRequest` and copy all cookies and header values from the current request into it...
- somehow trigger the browser (signalR) and instruct to launch an (ajax) request.

**Question**

Before reinventing the wheel I would like to know if is there an built in way to do it, or if is this a well known and already solved task?

Comment: What is your scenario?

Comment: Is it possible to somehow reuse some business logic services here to not post the request to the same web application? You will be in the same http session if this is the same request. Probably you can consider making some additional service with httpContextAccessor injected or injecting it into the existing one if you didn't use it there before

Comment: It is not about the reuse. It is about executing asynchronously while in the asyc execution keep the original context

Comment: So you mean that it needs to start execute in parallel with this request you posted and continue when your original request finishes, right?

Comment: No, that would be the async await pattern